# XPath search based on dynamic regular expressions

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have an XML like the one below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration>
        <Destinations>
            <Destination name="DEST1" >
                <From>AMA*</From>
            </Destination>

            <Destination name="DEST2" >
                <From>AMAZON</From>
            </Destination>

                           <Destination name="DEST3" >
                <From>EBAY</From>
            </Destination>

                           <Destination name="DEST4" >
                <From>*</From>
            </Destination>

        </Destinations>
    </Configuration>
```

I want to query and find out all desintations that match a provided input.

If i specify EBAY i want the xpath to return the node name = DEST3 and DEST4 (which doesn't care about the value)  but if i specify AMAZON it needs to return DEST1, DEST2 and DEST4 as AMA* in DEST1 supports wild card character.

so far my XPath looks like this:

> /Destination[(From = '' or
>   From = '*' ) )]/@name

If input is specified i create the XPATH expressions dynamically and slot the incoming value in the  field

I have other elements in my XML besides From.

Appreciate if anyone could give pointers on this.

Thanks,
Manglu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The following XPath 2.0 expression expresses the required selection**:

```
  /*/*/*[From[matches($pPat, replace(., '\*', '.*'))]]
```

**Explanation**:

1. The **`$pPat`** variable contains the search pattern (such as 'EBAY', 'AMAZON', etc.).
2. The standard XPath 2.0 function `matches()` is used to match the value of any `From` element to the string pattern.
3. The value of any `From` element is converted to a standard regular expression as supported by XPath 2.0. For this purpose, any occurence of `'*'` (escaped as `"\*"` in order not to be taken as the special char `'*'` used in regexs but as a normal character) is replaced by the string `".*"`

**Testing**:

**I have used the following XSLT 2.0 transformation** and verified that the above XPath 2.0 expression selects the elements as expected. To use it, replace the value of the global parameter $pPat with any desired value.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="pPat" as="xs:string"
     select="'AMAZON'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vsrchResult" as="element()*"
     select="/*/*/*[From[matches($pPat, replace(., '\*', '.*'))]]"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$vsrchResult"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the originally-provided XML document**:

```
<Configuration>
    <Destinations>
        <Destination name="DEST1" >
            <From>AMA*</From>
        </Destination>
        <Destination name="DEST2" >
            <From>AMAZON</From>
        </Destination>
        <Destination name="DEST3" >
            <From>EBAY</From>
        </Destination>
        <Destination name="DEST4" >
            <From>*</From>
        </Destination>
    </Destinations>
</Configuration>
```

**the required output is produced**:

```
<Destination name="DEST1">
            <From>AMA*</From>
        </Destination><Destination name="DEST2">
            <From>AMAZON</From>
        </Destination><Destination name="DEST4">
            <From>*</From>
        </Destination>
```