# Select child nodes based on their contents

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, nodes

XML snippet:

```
<AA>
  <BB>foo</BB>
  <CC>bar</CC>
  <DD>baz</DD>
  <EE>bar</EE>
</AA>
```

How do I select all the child nodes of `<AA>` that have `bar` as its contents? In the example above, I'd want to select `<CC>` and `<EE>`. I'm thinking the solution is something like:

```
<xsl:template match="AA">
  <xsl:for-each select="???" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**One of the simplest solutions to the OP's question is the following XPath expression**:

```
*/*[.='bar']
```

**Do note, that no XSLT instruction is involved -- this is just an XPath expression**, so the question could only be tagged XPath.

**From here on, one could use this XPath expression in XSLT in various ways, such as to apply templates upon all selected nodes**.

For example, below is an XSLT transformation that takes the XML document and produces another one, in which all elements - children of `<AA>` whose contents is not equal to `"bar"` are deleted:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AA">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*[. = 'bar']"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the original XML document**:

```
<AA>
    <BB>foo</BB>
    <CC>bar</CC>
    <DD>baz</DD>
    <EE>bar</EE>
</AA>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<AA>
   <CC>bar</CC>
   <EE>bar</EE>
</AA>
```

**Do note**:

In a match pattern we typically do not need to specify an absolute XPath expression, but just a relative one, so the full XPath expression is naturally simplified to this match pattern:

```
*[. = 'bar']
```

Comment: Thanks! Your other post was helpful as well, as the next extension would be using regular expressions for the selection:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539781/xpath-search-based-on-dynamic-regular-expressions

Comment: @zhen You are welcome. Only keep in mind that the RegEx solution is in XPath 2.0 -- there isn't such convenient way to do this in XPath 1.0